# DLRS - Is there a way to trigger the recalculation in real-time off of a relationship criteria field?

Tags: dlrs

Summary:
We are using DLRS jobs to monitor the quantity on Quote Lines as the Quote navigate through various statuses, and this lives on a separate object. This then gets updated on a related object (let's call it Quote Rollup).

The Quote Rollup object that has 3 fields that roll up the Quote **Line's** `Quantity` across the Quotes that are in "Draft", "Presented", "Accepted" - `Draft_Quantity__c`, `Presented_Quantity__c`, `Accepted_Quantity__c`, respectively.

DLRS Job Setup Example (field names changed for business reasons):
[image: DLRS Job Setup]

Scenario:

- Given a Quote is in Draft with a single line that has a Quantity of 100
- When the Quote's Status changes from Draft to Presented,
- Then the Quote Rollup field
  `Draft_Quantity__c` should be set `0`, and the
  `Presented_Quantity__c` field should be set to `100`.

**However**, since the the Quote Line's quantity itself did not change and the status field is on its parent, the DLRS job does not run. Is there any way to do this with DLRS? Or do I need to create a new custom trigger?

Comment: DLRS requires DML to occur on the child object to trigger the rollup logic

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for DLRS to support this, nor is there any reason to actually write any code if you just need a simple update. Just set up a Record-Triggered Flow (after save) on the parent object that updates its children. DLRS will perform the calculation in real-time if configured to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I may have simplified it just a little too much. The field we're triggering off of is actually a parent field. Let me edit the psot.

Comment: I have updated it to better reflect the hierarchy, though the screenshot should show the relationship criteria as "Quote.Status = 'Presented'" and the relationship criteria fields as "Quote.Status".

Comment: @MayaTran I'm pretty sure my answer still stands. If the parent updates the child in any way, that should be sufficient for DLRS to do its thing.

Comment: Sounds feasible. Thanks! I think the answer to this question though, is no you cannot retrigger the DLRS calcs if the field itself is not changing.